# How to replace a first step or landing?

Tags: stairs

Just moved into a new (to us) house and one curve of the bottom step was falling apart. I would like to replace the bottom two steps with plain steps like the rest of the staircase. I’m hoping to get a read on how complicated and to go about it? Thank you!
[image]
[image]

Comment: If you remove that landing **sub-tread** and look underneath, you'll be able to see if the existing staircase already has a stringer that can simply have another tread added.  I suggest doing that and post updated pictures.  By the way, staircase projects can be complex; I did several in my previous home and I bought a great book *Building Stairs* by Andy Engel.  Check your local library's web site to see if you can borrow it or a similar illustrated book.  It'll help a lot.  The book is obviously on amazon, too https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00LTYC3C4/

Comment: FYI the bottom step might not meet code if you make the steps straight. The bottom landing needs to be something like 36" square

Comment: I agree with @Ack. By the look of the pics, in your new design when you step off of the bottom tread your nose will be hitting a wall.